# Sapphire Pulse AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT 4G graphics card with a ASUS P7P55D-E LX motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, amd-radeon

Is the [Sapphire Pulse AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT 4G](https://www.sapphiretech.com/en/consumer/pulse-radeon-rx-5500-xt-4g-gddr6) graphics card compatible with the [ASUS P7P55D-E LX](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55DE_LX/HelpDesk/) motherboard?

Power-on self test seems fine, but as soon as it's time to boot, the screen goes black, the keyboard becomes inactive, and nothing else happens until I reset or power off.

There are rumours on Internet forums that recent Sapphire graphics cards may require UEFI, and this motherboard has only legacy BIOS.  I have the latest BIOS firmware, 1701.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BIOS settings’ Tools tab, ensure that `Express Gate` is set to either `Auto` or `Enabled`.  I don't think this setting *should* make any difference to this issue, but it does.